# When i choose 4 mars why does it start at 0.4992 and not 49.92 what do i do?

Tags: c#, math

```
using System;

namespace pel
{
    class Program
    {
        static double convert(int choice, double on_earth)
        {
            double on_planet = 0;
            if (choice == 1)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 38) / 100;
            else if (choice == 2)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 0.78) / 100;
            else if (choice == 3)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 100) / 100;
            else if (choice == 4)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 0.39) / 100;
            else if (choice == 5)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 2.65) / 100;
            else if (choice == 6)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 1.17) / 100;
            else if (choice == 7)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 1.05) / 100;
            else if (choice == 8)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 1.23) / 100;
            return on_planet;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] planets = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
            double on_earth = 0;
            int choice = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your current earth weight:");
            while (true)
            {
                on_earth = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                if (on_earth < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You can't weight a negative amount");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter again");
                    continue;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("I have information on the following planets: \n1 Mercury\n2 Venus\n3 Earth\n4 Mars\n5 Jupiter\n6 Saturn\n7 Uranus\n8 Neptune");
            Console.WriteLine("Planet choice:");
            while (true)
            {
                choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (choice < 1 || choice > 8)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid choice");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter again");
                    continue;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("On Earth, you weigh " + on_earth + " but on " + planets[choice - 1] + " you would weigh " + convert(choice, on_earth) + " pounds.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should put `on_earth * 39.0) / 100;` instead of `on_earth * 0.39) / 100;`, note `39.0` and `0.39`. Please use eitfer fractions or per cents

Answer (score 2):

You should use either *fractions* (say `* 0.39`) or *per cents* (`* 39) / 100`), but not a combination:

**Your code amended:**

```
        static double convert(int choice, double on_earth)
        {
            double on_planet = 0;
            if (choice == 1)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 0.38);
            else if (choice == 2)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 0.78);
            else if (choice == 3)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 1.0);
            else if (choice == 4)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 0.39);
            else if (choice == 5)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 2.65);
            else if (choice == 6)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 1.17);
            else if (choice == 7)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 1.05);
            else if (choice == 8)
                on_planet = (on_earth * 1.23);
            return on_planet;
        }
```

A better choice is to *extract model*:

```
// With model extracted it's much easier to see the wrong figures
static double[] s_OnPlanets = new double[] {
  0.38, 0.78, 1.00, 0.39, 2.65, 1.17, 1.05, 1.23
};

// Now we have no need in that many ifs:
static double convert(int choice, double on_earth) =>
  s_OnPlanets[choice - 1] * on_earth;
```